# How to calculate the SUM of a temp column created from a query

Tags: php, mysql

My query is working, but I need to calculate the total of a column which is created from the query, I am using a normal php script to add the value (in money) of the accumulated working hours, this also works perfectly. But how do I then get the Sum or total of this column, which should give me a single figure, used in an echo line as "....accumulated salary for the period is ***_***", see second last line from my script.

Following is a snipped of the script:

```
<?php
    include("../xxx");
    $cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname)
        or die ("Couldn't connect to server.");
    $query = "SELECT 
                ea.`employee_id`, 
                e.`employee_surname`, 
                e.`employee_first_name`, 
                e.`employee_second_name`,
                e.`employee_salary`, 
                FORMAT((IF((SUM(ea.`empl_attendance_total`))<180,(SUM(ea.`empl_attendance_total`)),180)),1) AS nt,
                FORMAT((IF(((SUM(ea.`empl_attendance_total`))-(SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(ea.empl_attendance_date) > 5 THEN ea.empl_attendance_total END)))<=180,
                    0,(IF(((SUM(ea.`empl_attendance_total`))-(SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(ea.empl_attendance_date) > 5 THEN ea.empl_attendance_total END)))>180,
                    ((SUM(ea.`empl_attendance_total`))-(SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(ea.empl_attendance_date) > 5 THEN ea.empl_attendance_total END)))-180,
                0)))),1) AS ot,
                FORMAT((IF((SUM(ea.`empl_attendance_total`))>180,
                IF((SUM(ea.`empl_attendance_total`))-180>=(SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(ea.empl_attendance_date) > 5 THEN ea.empl_attendance_total END)),
                (SUM(CASE WHEN WEEKDAY(ea.empl_attendance_date) > 5 THEN ea.empl_attendance_total END)),(SUM(ea.`empl_attendance_total`))-180),
                0)),1) AS st,
                FORMAT((SUM(ea.`empl_attendance_total`)),1) AS total
            FROM
                empl_attendance ea 
            JOIN 
                employee e 
            ON ea.`employee_id` = e.`employee_id` 
            WHERE  ea.`empl_attendance_date` BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date' 
            GROUP BY `employee_id`";
    $result = mysqli_query($cxn,$query)
        or die ("Couldn't execute query.");
$total_salary = 0; 
    /* Displays items already in table */
    echo "<table><br>
    <tr>
     <th>Empl No</th>
     <th>Empl Name</th>
     <th>N/T (1.0)</th>
     <th>O/T (1.5)</th>
     <th>S/T (2.0)</th>
     <th>Total Hrs</th>
     <th>Est Salary</th>
    </tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
    extract($row); 
    $sal = ((($employee_salary/180)*$nt)+((($employee_salary/180)*$ot)*1.5)+((($employee_salary/180)*$st)*2)); 
    $salary = number_format($sal, 2, '.', ','); 

    // add this salary to the total 
    $total_salary += $sal; 

    echo "<tr>\n
            <td>$employee_id</td>\n
            <td>$employee_surname, $employee_first_name $employee_second_name</td>\n
            <td>$nt</td>\n
            <td>$ot</td>\n
            <td>$st</td>\n
            <td>$total</td>\n
            <td>R $salary</td>\n
            </tr>\n"; 
} 
    // change the format of the salary variable
$acc_sal = number_format($total_salary, 2, '.', ',');
echo "</table><br>"; 
echo "Accumulated Salary for the selected period is<b> R $acc_sal<b>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fairly easy way of doing this would be to define a new variable (eg `$total_salary`) before the `while` loop and adding each salary to it.

So you would have (code is truncated somewhat):

```
...
$total_salary = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    extract($row);
    $sal = ((($employee_salary/180)*$nt)+((($employee_salary/180)*$ot)*1.5)+((($employee_salary/180)*$st)*2));
    $salary = number_format($sal, 2, '.', ',');

    // add this salary to the total
    $total_salary += $sal;

    echo "... row markup ...";
}
echo "</table><br>";
echo "<b> Accumulated Salary for the selected period is $total_salary<b>";
```

P.S.: That's one awesome query!!! :)

Comment: Thanx for the help @froddd, the formula gave me a wrong total though, but the fix was an easy one - I have updated my original script with the corrections and is working fine now.

Comment: Thanx for the help @froddd, the formula gave me a wrong total though, but the fix was an easy one - trying to formulate the  formatted number gave the incorrect total, so I only used the unformatted variable ($sal) and formatted it later withing the script. I have updated my original script with the corrections and is working fine now. Once again, thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction... Jay

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have noticed `$salary` was the formatted one... Obviously needed to use `$sal`. Do'h! I've updated the answer too, feel free to accept it if that's what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're only using GROUP BY on one column, check out the WITH ROLLUP option, which will return you one more row from the database.

If you do this, leave a huge comment in your code, because future developers may not be expecting that extra row.

Comment: Hi @Alain Collins, I have never even heard of WITH ROLLUP, thus you can be sure that I will look into that, maybee not something I will use here, but I may have somewhere where it can come in handy. Thank you for the feedback... Jay